# Choose function based on class

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Is there anyway, even using a bizarre combination of GHC extensions, make a function `h` like the following psudeocode:

```
f :: (C1 a) => a -> Int
g :: (C2 a) => a -> Int

h x = 
  if (isOfClass C1 x) then (f x) 
  else if (isOfClass C2 x) then (g x)
  else COMPILE_ERROR
```

Note that if `x` is both of class `C1` and `C2` I don't mind if I get inconsistent behaviour depending on what's in scope.

Comment: Do you have a use case in mind?

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the value in another type, for example `Either` or a custom type

Example with `Either`:

```
h :: (C1 a, C2 b) => Either a b -> Int
h = either f g
```

Answer (score 3):

This is impossible, since it would cope with separate compilation. Consider

```
module A where

data A = A Int

isOfClassEq :: a -> Bool
isOfClassEq = <<some magic here>>

test :: Bool
test = isOfClassEq (A 42)
```

and

```
module Main where
import A
instance Eq A where (A x) == (A y) = x == y
main = print test
```

If I opened module `A` in GHCi, `test` would evaluate to `False`. So, the code associated to `test` must return `False`. Instead if I load module `Main` and run `main` I should see `True`. If we have separate compilation, since the compiler can not know about the instance when compiling module `A`, is has to generate code for `test` which checks the class membership at runtime.

This would require GHC to keep *runtime* all the type information, including a type<->class table to perform checks. However, Haskell is designed so that type information can be discarded during compile time.